# Error connecting to ASP.NET IIS7 hosted website getting error Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, sockets, dns, iis-7, webserver

I have spent the entire day reading through stack and googling, but nothing is working. The issue i'm hitting is the following:

I'm trying to set up my ASP.NET web solution which was working once upon a time, but after many reboots later for some reason it stopped working. I have my bindings set up to point to * for ip and going to port 80, and externally i have the local ip mapped to port 8700 with my external host address mapped. I can hit it fine entering localhost in my browser locally, but thats about it.

I have my router forwarding traffic to 8700 to the local ip of the web server. I also have DMZ hosting set up for that ip as well. Turning my firewall totally off does nothing.

I have checked my app pool and site and both services are running (naturally as i can hit localhost). Like i said, it ran before, so i know the rudimentary setup is sound, its just something has changed to prevent it from working now.

Here is the full return i'm hitting. Any help to put me over this hurdle is greatly appreciated. Like i said i spent all day on this and i need it functional.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my binding info as it is set currently:

```
Type HTTP, Port 80, IP Address *; 
Type net.tcp, Binding info 808:*; 
Type net.pipe, Binding info *; 
Type net.msmq, binding info localhost; 
Type msmq.formatname, binding info localhost; 
Type HTTP, host name <host info here>, port 80, ip address <local ip>; 
Type HTTP, host name <host info here>, port 8700, ip address <local ip>.
```

I know i have a ton of bindings. The default settings were retained and i simply edited and added the last two to the list. I bind 80 for local traffic hitting, and 8700 for external traffic as i had issues getting external communication from port 80.

Error on web return:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x2afa): This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server]
   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address, Boolean includeIPv6) +2974089
   System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress) +8284466
   SolutionsWeb.index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +56
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1087.0
```

Comment: `SolutionsWeb.index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)` <- something is going on there. You need to share the relevant code with us.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved. It was down to a DNS grab in the page load properties. Would have never thought of checking source as, like i said, it once worked. For some reason (perhaps browser restrictions) it stopped working. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction Mason!